# Meaning of '{ }' in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

What does assigning a variable to `{}`, mean? Is that initializing it to a function? I have code in a javascript file that says this

```
GLGE.Wavefront = function(uid) {
    GLGE.Assets.registerAsset(this,uid);
    this.multimaterials = [];
    this.materials      = {}; // <---
    this.instances      = [];
    this.renderCaches   = [];
    this.queue          = [];
};
```

how is that assignment different from an array? Is it a type of array?

Comment: It is sometimes called an "associative array," meaning one where the keys need not be numbers. But in Javascript, an associative array is really just an object. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> What does assigning a variable to {}, mean?

It is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals) (with no properties of its own).

> Is that initializing it to a function?

No, that would be `= function () { }`.

> how is that assignment different from an array?

An array has a bunch of features not found in a basic object, such as `.length` and a bundle of methods.

Objects are often used to store arbitrary key/value pairs. Arrays are for ordered values.

Comment: Yes. Try this experiment in your JS console: `foo = {}; foo['bar'] = 1; foo.baz = 2; foo;`. On the last step you should be able to inspect the foo object and see that two properties were set: `foo['bar'] =` and `foo.bar = ` are the same. If you try this again, starting with an array instead (`foo = []`), you will only be able to assign values to numerical keys using the `foo[key]` form (`foo.0 = `, for example, won't work).

Comment: @Nathan Long — That isn't true, Arrays are Objects with bells on. You can give them whatever properties you like, it is just generally bad practise. Th reason it doesn't show up in a JS console is because most JS consoles only bother showing the numerical properties (because that makes sense when rendering an array). Going to `theArray.foo` directly will still give you the value you put in.

Answer (score 14):

This is javascript object notation. Particularly `{}` means empty object, the same as `new Object();`. See [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Comment: That website, as explained on it, is about JSON. Not the actual object notation found in the language Javascript.

Comment: `JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format... JSON is a text format that is completely language independent` That doesn't seem to fit a question about a particular javascript language feature.

Comment: I can't understand the tremendous quantity of votes that this question and its answers seem to be attracting.

Comment: @Tomalak, davin: "JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript." Which means that anything described in JSON is also JavaScript. I wouldn't have chosen to provide a link to something about JSON, personally, but it's still a valid response. And Tomalak, if you think this question and its answers are really attracting a "tremendous quantity" of votes, then you need to take a good look at the truly popular questions and answers on SO.

Comment: @JAB: "Tremendous" meaning "Disproportionally tremendous".

Comment: @JAB: Yes, but that doesn't mean that JSON _is_ Javascript.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal That may be true, but the json site is one of the most succinct descriptions of JavaScript Object Notation that I've seen.

Comment: @Barry: I agree. However, again, this question is not about JSON.

Comment: Couldn't you think of JSON as merely the notation used to describe javascript objects?

Comment: It isn't, it is a subset of it… well… [almost a subset](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset)

Answer (score 10):

That would be an empty JavaScript object.

Answer (score 2):

Using `{}` creates an object. You can use the object like a hash-map or similar to how you can use arrays in PHP.

```
var obj = {};
obj['test'] = 'valuehere';
obj.secondWay = 'secondValue';
```

and you could access them by calling `obj.test` and `obj['secondWay']`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an initialized empty object, eg. an object of no particular type. It serves to provide a definition for `this.materials` so that the code won't have to check it for `null` or being defined later.

Answer (score 0):

It does create an empty object.

```
var myObj = {};
```

Within an object you can define key/value pairs, e.g.:

```
myObj.color = 'red';
```

A value can be a function, too:

```
myObj.getColor = function() { return this.color };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's JON (Javascript Object Notation) for creating a new empty object. Almost equal in idea to how you'd normally do Object x = new Object() in java, minus the initialization part...

Comment: It isn't minus the initialization part, it just uses JavaScript syntax.